# How do we see that the shape of an equation is closed?

Tags: calculus, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

Actually, I would like to understand :
When we have an equation , can we decide that its shape closed curve? 
For instance, for the equation:
$$((x+y)^2) + 2((x^4)/4-(x^5)/5)=C$$
For which values of C makes the shape of this equation closed?

Comment: Could you be more precise in your definition of "closed curve"?

Comment: I intend to say "simple closed curve" or Jordan curve. The answer is helpful for me. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

For any value of $C$ the graph is closed. To see this, define a function $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ by $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2+2\left(\dfrac{x^4}{4}-\dfrac{x^5}{5}\right)-C$. Clearly $f$ is continuous and so $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:(x+y)^2+2\left(\dfrac{x^4}{4}-\dfrac{x^5}{5}\right)=C\right\}$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R^2$ as this set is the inverse image of the closed subset $\{0\}$ under the continuous function $f$.

Comment: I think you are using a different definition of "closed curve" from the OP's. I think he means a [Jordan curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Topology), whereas you mean a topological closed set.

Comment: Yes I think it is asked to show that the curve is topologically closed.

Comment: I'm not so sure, though he has not answered my question. I think he also wants the "shape" to be non-empty and bounded. You have not shown this... but the fault is the OP's, not yours. I give you +1.

Comment: I sketch the graph of the function. But I did not get the simple closed curve everywhere. For instance if $x\in (3,5)$ the graph is open. I mean it is not a simple closed curve. I am confused again.